# Why does my program not use the proxy specified

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying the request module with proxies by sending a POST request to https://httpbin.org/post. Even though I specify a proxy, the response always gives my own IP.
Here is my code:

```
def r():
    proxies = {'http': 'http://82.200.233.4:3128'}
    r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', proxies=proxies)
    return r.text

print(r())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem over here is that you are trying to access a website over `https` protocol, however you have only given a proxy for `http` protocol.

If you make your proxies list like this:

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://82.200.233.4:3128', 'https': 'http://82.200.233.4:3128'}
```

It should work fine :)

Comment: This worked, thanks! so it always has to have both?

Comment: Yes if you wish to work with both `http` and `https`.

Comment: @ShujaHaider: If you do not want to specify this manually in the code you can set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY in the environment variables.  You can read more about it [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/advanced/#proxies). Also, welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thanks, how do I know if a proxy will work in this configuration?

Comment: Requests lib tries to obtain the proxies from those variables. You can read more about it in the link j mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use HTTPS proxy in requests.